# Parameter cannot be processed because the parameter name 't' is ambiguous

Tags: powershell

I'm writing a PowerShell function below:

```
function LinkChecker {
    param (
        [string]$Url,
        [string]$ConfigFile,
        [int]$Threads = 10,
        [switch]$ListPlugins,
        [string]$Debug,
        [string]$FileOutput,
        [switch]$NoStatus,
        [switch]$NoWarnings,
        [string]$Output = "text",
        [string]$CookieFile,
        [switch]$NoRobots,
        [switch]$CheckExtern,
        [string[]]$IgnoreUrl,
        [string[]]$NoFollowUrl,
        [switch]$Password,
        [int]$RecursionLevel = -1,
        [int]$Timeout=999,
        [string]$User,
        [string]$UserAgent = "LinkChecker/X.Y"
    )

    $linkCheckerCmd = "linkchecker"

    $args = @()
    if ($Url) { $args += $Url }
    if ($ConfigFile) { $args += "-f $ConfigFile" }
    if ($Threads -gt 0) { $args += "-t $Threads" }
    if ($ListPlugins) { $args += "--list-plugins" }
    if ($Debug) { $args += "-D $Debug" }
    if ($FileOutput) { $args += "-F $FileOutput" }
    if ($NoStatus) { $args += "--no-status" }
    if ($NoWarnings) { $args += "--no-warnings" }
    if ($Output) { $args += "-o $Output" }
    if ($CookieFile) { $args += "--cookiefile $CookieFile" }
    if ($NoRobots) { $args += "--no-robots" }
    if ($CheckExtern) { $args += "--check-extern" }
    if ($IgnoreUrl) { $args += $IgnoreUrl | ForEach-Object { "--ignore-url $_" } }
    if ($NoFollowUrl) { $args += $NoFollowUrl | ForEach-Object { "--no-follow-url $_" } }
    if ($Password) { $args += "-p" }
    if ($RecursionLevel -ge 0) { $args += "-r $RecursionLevel" }
    if ($Timeout) { $args += "--timeout $Timeout" }
    if ($User) { $args += "-u $User" }
    if ($UserAgent) { $args += "--user-agent $UserAgent" }

    Invoke-Expression "$linkCheckerCmd $($args -join ' ')"
}
```

When I run my function with this:

```
LinkChecker -Url https://stackoverflow.com/
```

I will get the following error:

> LinkChecker: Parameter cannot be processed because the parameter name 't' is ambiguous. Possible matches include: -Threads -Timeout.

When I use the `LinkChecker` function, I don't want to use `-Threads` and `-Timeout` parameter. How to define my PowerShell function so that I can run this function correctly?

Comment: Inspect `$Error[0].CommandInvocation` immediately after the error occurs - does the `BoundParamaters` or `UnboundParameters` properties have unexpected values? Are they list parameter names or arguments you didn't pass?

Comment: Your function name and the name of the external command are clashing - you're running ```Invoke-Expression "linkchecker -t $Threads ... etc ..."``` but it's calling **your function** recursively, not the external command. The *symptomatic* error comes because your ```LinkChecker ``` function has two parameters that start with the letter ```T``` (```Threads``` and ```Timeout```), but the root cause is the name collision. Either rename your function or specify ```$linkCheckerCmd = "linkchecker.exe"```, *or* the fully qualified path - e.g. ```$linkCheckerCmd = "c:\temp\linkchecker.exe"```...

Comment: Renaming your function something that uses powershell naming conventions like ```Invoke-LinkChecker``` would also work, and be more idiomatic, and avoid the need to update the name / path for the external command...

Comment: After I renamed to `Invoke-LinkChecker`. Problem solved. Thank you guys!